# Is there a way to set a preprocessor variable to the value of a property?

Tags: wix, xsd, wix3

I have a WiX include file with the following code

```
<Fragment Id="PropertyFragment">
  <Property Id="DynamicLanguageCode" Value="[SystemLanguageID]" />
  <?define productLanguage = [DynamicLanguageCode]?>
</Fragment>
```

Now in my Product tag in my WiX script I'd like to set the Language attribute to the value of productLanguage, as it only takes localizable integers. Is there a way I can get my variable to be assigned the value of the property?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's important to clear up confusion around the difference between wix variables and windows installer properties.

A **wix variable** can be referenced as `$(var.foo)`. Such a variable can be defined by passing `-d` command line arguments to `candle.exe`. It can also be defined by the `<?define foo="bar"?>` syntax. A wix variable is a concept that only exists while building your setup. It is something that it is filled in by the wix preprocessor before anything else happens, much like `#define` statements in C++.

A **windows installer property** is something that is filled in during installation. One way to define properties is to put them in the [Property table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370908%28VS.85%29.aspx) of an MSI file. This is what the wix Property element does. Some (but not all) [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367869%28VS.85%29.aspx) used in a windows installer database allow you to reference such a property with the `[FOO]` syntax. One example of a data type which supports this is the [Shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371844%28VS.85%29.aspx) data type, used by the `Target` attribute of the wix [Shortcut](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_shortcut.htm) element. The [Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369747%28VS.85%29.aspx) datatype does **not** support this!

Answer (score 3):

Without arguing why, this could be done like that:

```
<Property Id="DynamicLanguageCode" Value="$(var.SystemLanguageID)" />
```